# php mysql database fetching of data only once

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing an application that will be used to send SMS. IMMEDIATELY the application gets the required values from another application and is supposed to send the message AUTOMATICALLY and immediately. I wish that someone would direct me on how I can make it automatic. If I select an id it's working but I wish for an automatic sending without repetition.

```
//I would want to have like an automatic retrieval any time it gets
$sql = "SELECT name,amount, trans_id, msisdn, time_paid FROM customer";

$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultarr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1); // fetch data

$name = $resultarr['name'];  // get the name from an array
$amount = $resultarr['amount']; // get the amount from the array
$transaction_id = $resultarr['trans_id'];  // get the transaction id from the array
$date = $resultarr['time_paid'];  // get time paid from array

$conn->close();

//the message to be sent
 $message = "Dear $name we have received $amount from you. MPESA     transaction Id $transaction_id on $date";

 $mobilenumber = $resultarr['msisdn']; // get mobile number from array
 $message_sent = $message;

 $serviceArguments = array(
        "mobilenumber" => $mobilenumber,
        "message" => $message_sent
       );
```

Comment: Put it on a cron? Would run once per minute, but for this use-case that sounds fair enough, especially if you do multiple in a single process instead of one as your code implies.

Comment: You should build it as a Service which can be called by other programms, not as a db driven solution

Comment: Okay, am getting the details from another program and I want it to send the message automatically once it gets them. Kindly, how do I go about the service? @Jens

Comment: You are not processing the query results in a loop _you probably should be_ You are not setting anything to say this row has been processed _You probably should be_ If you are running on UNIX look up [CRON Jobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) If you are running on Windows look up [TaskScheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler)

Comment: @RiggsFolly actually you brought up very ideal points. However, am still learning the language and I have no idea how to go about it. Kindly lead me

Comment: Research,Research,Research I gave you lots to look at, now it is your job to **hit the books** and **make google your friend** SO is **not a free coding service** As it stands this question is ___way to broad___ and is likely to get closed for that reason. Afterall I assume you are getting PAID for your work, we are not getting paid for our assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a cron job in your server, which will help you to send sms automatically.